# how to get a Python timing object to retain appropriate information within function and decorator scopes

Tags: python, function, scope, clock, timing

I'm writing a module for quick and easy timing in a Python program. The idea is that little instances of clocks can be created throughout the code. These clocks are available as objects that can be started, stopped, started again and queried. Any clocks instantiated are added to a module list of all clocks. At the conclusion of the program, a printout of all clocks (either a listing of all clocks or the means of all similar clocks) can be requested of this list.

I've got a lot of it working, but the timing of functions is still causing me difficulty. Specifically, the times measured for the functions are measured as 0 using either explicit clocks or using a decorator, when the time measured for functions 1 and 1 should be ~3 seconds and ~4 seconds respectively.

I suspect that I am not retaining the clock attribute `_startTimeTmp` in an appropriate way (it can be reset for the purposes of internal calculations).

I would really appreciate some guidance on getting the timers working correctly. I've got myself a bit confused on how to solve it!

I'm aware that the code may look slightly long, but I've minimized it as much as I know how to without obscuring the vision of what I'm trying to do overall (so that any suggestions proposed don't remove critical functionality). I do think it's reasonably clear how it works, at least.

## module (shijian.py):

```
from __future__ import division
import os
import time
import uuid as uuid
import datetime
import inspect
import functools

def _main():
    global clocks
    clocks = Clocks()

def time_UTC(
    style = None
    ):
    return(
        style_datetime_object(
            datetimeObject = datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            style = style
        )
    )

def style_datetime_object(
    datetimeObject = None,
    style = "YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSS"
    ):
    # filename safe
    if style == "YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSSZ":
        return(datetimeObject.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%SZ'))
    # microseconds
    elif style == "YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSSMMMMMMZ":
        return(datetimeObject.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%fZ'))
    # elegant
    elif style == "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS UTC":
        return(datetimeObject.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ'))
    # UNIX time in seconds with second fraction
    elif style == "UNIX time S.SSSSSS":
        return(
            (datetimeObject -\
            datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()
        )
    # UNIX time in seconds rounded
    elif style == "UNIX time S":
        return(
            int((datetimeObject -\
            datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds())
        )
    # filename safe
    else:
        return(datetimeObject.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%SZ'))

def UID():
    return(str(uuid.uuid4()))

class Clock(object):

    def __init__(
        self,
        name               = None,
        start              = True
        ):
        self._name         = name
        self._start        = start # Boolean start clock on instantiation
        self._startTime    = None # internal (value to return)
        self._startTimeTmp = None # internal (value for calculations)
        self._stopTime     = None # internal (value to return)
        self._updateTime   = None # internal
        # If no name is specified, generate a unique one.
        if self._name is None:
            self._name     = UID()
        # If a global clock list is detected, add a clock instance to it.
        if "clocks" in globals():
            clocks.add(self)
        self.reset()
        if self._start:
            self.start()

    def start(self):
        self._startTimeTmp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        self._startTime    = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def stop(self):
        self._updateTime   = None
        self._startTimeTmp = None
        self._stopTime     = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    # Update the clock accumulator.
    def update(self):
        if self._updateTime:        
            self.accumulator += (
                datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self._updateTime
            )
        else:
            self.accumulator += (
                datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self._startTimeTmp
            )
        self._updateTime   = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def reset(self):
        self.accumulator   = datetime.timedelta(0)
        self._startTimeTmp = None

    # If the clock has a start time, add the difference between now and the
    # start time to the accumulator and return the accumulation. If the clock
    # does not have a start time, return the accumulation.
    def elapsed(self):
        if self._startTimeTmp:
            self.update()
        return(self.accumulator)

    def name(self):
        return(self._name)

    def time(self):
        return(self.elapsed().total_seconds())

    def startTime(self):
        if self._startTime:
            return(style_datetime_object(datetimeObject = self._startTime))
        else:
            return("none")

    def stopTime(self):
        if self._stopTime:
            return(style_datetime_object(datetimeObject = self._stopTime))
        else:
            return("none")

    def report(
        self
        ):
        string = "clock attribute".ljust(39)     + "value"
        string += "\nname".ljust(40)             + self.name()
        string += "\ntime start (s)".ljust(40)   + self.startTime()
        string += "\ntime stop (s)".ljust(40)    + self.stopTime()
        string += "\ntime elapsed (s)".ljust(40) + str(self.time())
        string += "\n"
        return(string)

    def printout(self):
        print(self.report())

def timer(function):

    #@functools.wraps(function)
    def decoration(
        *args,
        **kwargs
        ):
        arguments = inspect.getcallargs(function, *args, **kwargs)
        clock     = Clock(name = function.__name__)
        result    = function(*args, **kwargs)
        clock.stop()

    return(decoration)

class Clocks(object):

    def __init__(
        self
        ):
        self._listOfClocks       = []
        self._defaultReportStyle = "statistics"

    def add(
        self,
        clock
        ):
        self._listOfClocks.append(clock)

    def report(
        self,
        style = None
        ):
        if style is None:
            style = self._defaultReportStyle
        if self._listOfClocks != []:
            if style == "statistics":
                # Create a dictionary of clock types with corresponding lists of
                # times for all instances.
                dictionaryOfClockTypes = {}
                # Get the names of all clocks and add them to the dictionary.
                for clock in self._listOfClocks:
                    dictionaryOfClockTypes[clock.name()] = []
                # Record the values of all clocks for their respective names in
                # the dictionary.
                for clock in self._listOfClocks:
                    dictionaryOfClockTypes[clock.name()].append(clock.time())
                # Create a report, calculating the average value for each clock
                # type.
                string = "clock type".ljust(39) + "mean time (s)"
                for name, values in dictionaryOfClockTypes.iteritems():
                    string += "\n" +\
                              str(name).ljust(39) + str(sum(values)/len(values))
                string += "\n"
            elif style == "full":
                # Create a report, listing the values of all clocks.
                string = "clock".ljust(39) + "time (s)"
                for clock in self._listOfClocks:
                    string += "\n" +\
                              str(clock.name()).ljust(39) + str(clock.time())
                string += "\n"
        else:
            string = "no clocks"
        return(string)

    def printout(
        self,
        style = None
        ):
        if style is None:
            style = self._defaultReportStyle
        print(self.report(style = style))

_main()
```

## main code example (examples.py):

```
import shijian
import time
import inspect

def main():

    print("create clock alpha")
    alpha = shijian.Clock(name = "alpha")
    print("clock alpha start time: {time}".format(time = alpha.startTime()))
    print("sleep 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("clock alpha current time (s): {time}".format(time = alpha.time()))

    print("\ncreate clock beta")
    beta = shijian.Clock(name = "beta")
    print("clock beta start time: {time}".format(time = beta.startTime()))
    print("clock beta stop time: {time}".format(time = beta.stopTime()))
    print("sleep 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("clock beta current time (s): {time}".format(time = beta.time()))
    print("stop clock beta")
    beta.stop()
    print("clock beta start time: {time}".format(time = beta.startTime()))
    print("clock beta stop time: {time}".format(time = beta.stopTime()))
    print("sleep 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("clock beta start time: {time}".format(time = beta.startTime()))
    print("clock beta stop time: {time}".format(time = beta.stopTime()))
    print("clock beta current time (s): {time}".format(time = beta.time()))

    print("\nclock beta printout:\n")
    beta.printout()

    print("create two gamma clocks")
    gamma = shijian.Clock(name = "gamma")
    gamma = shijian.Clock(name = "gamma")
    print("sleep 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\ncreate two unnamed clocks")
    delta = shijian.Clock()
    epsilon = shijian.Clock()
    print("sleep 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\nrun function 1 (which is timed using internal clocks)")
    function1()

    print("\nrun function 2 (which is timed using a decorator)")
    function2()

    print("\nclocks full printout:\n")
    shijian.clocks.printout(style = "full")

    print("clocks statistics printout:\n")
    shijian.clocks.printout()

def function1():
    functionName = inspect.stack()[0][3]
    clock = shijian.Clock(name = functionName)
    print("initiate {functionName}".format(functionName = functionName))
    time.sleep(3)
    print("terminate {functionName}".format(functionName = functionName))
    clock.stop()

@shijian.timer
def function2():
    functionName = inspect.stack()[0][3]
    print("initiate {functionName}".format(functionName = functionName))
    time.sleep(4)
    print("terminate {functionName}".format(functionName = functionName))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## example terminal output:

```
create clock alpha
clock alpha start time: 2015-01-03T090124Z
sleep 2 seconds
clock alpha current time (s): 2.000887

create clock beta
clock beta start time: 2015-01-03T090126Z
clock beta stop time: none
sleep 2 seconds
clock beta current time (s): 2.002123
stop clock beta
clock beta start time: 2015-01-03T090126Z
clock beta stop time: 2015-01-03T090128Z
sleep 2 seconds
clock beta start time: 2015-01-03T090126Z
clock beta stop time: 2015-01-03T090128Z
clock beta current time (s): 2.002123

clock beta printout:

clock attribute                        value
name                                   beta
time start (s)                         2015-01-03T090126Z
time stop (s)                          2015-01-03T090128Z
time elapsed (s)                       2.002123

create two gamma clocks
sleep 2 seconds

create two unnamed clocks
sleep 2 seconds

run function 1 (which is timed using internal clocks)
initiate function1
terminate function1

run function 2 (which is timed using a decorator)
initiate function2
terminate function2

clocks full printout:

clock                                  time (s)
alpha                                  17.023659
beta                                   2.002123
gamma                                  11.018138
gamma                                  11.018138
1919f9de-85ce-48c9-b1c8-5164f3a2633e   9.017148
d24c818c-f4e6-48d0-ad72-f050a5cf86d3   9.017027
function1                              0.0
function2                              0.0

clocks statistics printout:

clock type                             mean time (s)
function1                              0.0
function2                              0.0
1919f9de-85ce-48c9-b1c8-5164f3a2633e   9.017283
beta                                   2.002123
alpha                                  17.023834
d24c818c-f4e6-48d0-ad72-f050a5cf86d3   9.017163
gamma                                  11.0182835
```

Comment: I would recommend you have a look at [the Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Was there anything you saw that was egregiously wrong? I know I start the functions a little unusually and some newline usage makes things look a bit odd (e.g. for the mathematics), but this is to address line width restrictions.

Comment: `pylint` gives 102 messages for `shijian.py` (including one error in Python 3, where `dict.iteritems` doesn't exist) and 29 for `examples.py`. These don't affect the functionality (in 2.x) but if you want other Python developers to read and use your code, making it look like Python would be a good start.

Comment: It's not a pleasure to read, since you've got tons of comments in it. Real clean code doesn't have any comments in it, but docstrings (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring)… Albeit, it would be nice if you've extracted the main problem. Also what the heck is that awful multiline function definition (you even make a three-liner out of the `def __init__(self):`???)

Comment: Thank you [jonrsharpe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) and [septi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/531222/septi) for your helpful advice and comments. Some of the code is odd because it is unfinished, but a lot is because I am still learning. I shall take every one of your suggestions into account when improving my code here and in future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Clock` does not get `update`d when it is `stop`ped. The minimal fix is:

```
def stop(self):
    self.update()
    self._updateTime   = None
    self._startTimeTmp = None
    self._stopTime     = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

You have three other errors:

- You should test for `None` by identity (`if foo is not None`) not truthiness (`if foo`), to avoid issues with `False`-y values that aren't `None`;
- `shijian.timer` doesn't `return result`, so although the timing will work you'll break any code that expects a return from the decorated function; and
- If you want the code to work in Python 2 and 3, you can't use `dict.iteritems`, which doesn't exist in the latter. If you only want it to work in Python 2, either `from __future__ import print_function` or use `print whatever` rather than `print(whatever)`.

Additionally, your code is not at all compliant with [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (or, worse, even internally consistent - compare the definition of `Clock.start` with that of `Clock.report`, for example).

There is also room for improvement in the design and functionality (e.g. `Clock.name` could be a `@property`, and I would separate the table printing from the generation of results). You should consider submitting your code for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), once you have:

- completed;
- tested; and
- style-guide-complianced it

(you might find using [`pylint`](http://www.pylint.org/) helpful for the latter).

Finally, I assume you're doing this for learning purposes rather than because you need the functionality, as Python [has its own profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).

Comment: Yes! The update on stopping the clock was what I was missing. That's well-spotted. Thank you very much for your guidance on that and for your additional assistance with the decorator, with writing for Python 3 and with writing more Pythonic code generally. Some of my code here is not brilliant because it is not finished and some of it because I am still learning.

Thank you also for your suggestions regarding peer review of code and profilers (with which I am not familiar -- the term is new to me). I'll dive into learning about these. :)